# Dropdown menu issue with json

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a Car website and I added a simple json file with data of each car brand and their models.

```
[
  {"id": "1", "brand": "Seat", "models": ["Alhambra", "Altea", "Altea XL", "Arosa", "Cordoba", "Cordoba Vario", "Exeo", "Ibiza", "Ibiza ST", "Exeo ST", "Leon", "Leon ST", "Inca", "Mii", "Toledo"]},
  {"id": "2", "brand": "Renault", "models": ["Captur", "Clio", "Clio Grandtour", "Espace", "Express", "Fluence", "Grand Espace", "Grand Modus", "Grand Scenic", "Kadjar", "Kangoo", "Kangoo Express", "Zoé"]},
  {"id": "3", "brand": "Audi", "models": ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A4 Allroad", "A4 Avant", "A5",  "A6", "A7", "A8", "A8 Long", "Q3", "Q5", "Q7", "R8", "RS4 Cabriolet", "RS4/RS4 Avant", "RS5", "RS6 Avant", "RS7"]}
]
```

I added a dropdown menu where when I select a specific brand it will show me only the models of that brand. For example, if I Pick Audi I will only get "A1, A2, A3, A4, etc.". However, right now when I pick my car brand I get all those brand models in one line. How can I make it so each model is on a separate line instead of all clustered in one?
Here are pictures of how it looks now:
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnJbg.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKBuD.png)

My code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default class simpleData extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cars: [],
      models: ""
    };

    this.handleSubmitCar = this.handleSubmitCar.bind(this);
  }



  handleSubmitCar(event) {
    alert("Your selected value is: " + this.state.models);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  handleChangeCar = event => {
    this.setState({ models: event.target.value });
  };

  getUnique(arr, comp) {
    const unique = arr
      //store the comparison values in array
      .map(e => e[comp])

      // store the keys of the unique objects
      .map((e, i, final) => final.indexOf(e) === i && i)

      // eliminate the dead keys & store unique objects
      .filter(e => arr[e])

      .map(e => arr[e]);

    return unique;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const cars = require("./cars.json");
    this.setState({ cars: cars });
  }

  render() {

    const uniqueCar = this.getUnique(this.state.cars, "brand");

    const cars = this.state.cars;
    const models = this.state.models;

    const filterDropdown = cars.filter(function(result) {
      return result.brand === models;
    });

    return (
      <div>      
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmitCar}>
          <br />
          <br />
          <label>
            Car brand
            <select
              value={this.state.models}
              onChange={this.handleChangeCar}
            >
              {uniqueCar.map(models => (
                <option key={models.id} value={models.brand}>
                  {models.brand}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" /><br/>
          Car Model
            <select>
            {filterDropdown.map(models => (
              <option key={models.id}>
                {models.models}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>

        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your map function

```
        {filterDropdown.map(models => (
          <option key={models.id}>
            {models.models}
          </option>
        ))}
```

You need a way to map the models that the user selected, the selected car's models, which is `models.models`

Instead what's happening is you're filtering the selected car in the original json, and returning any value that matches the selected car, that returns an array, which stores only 1 object, the selected car itself, and you're mapping over that array.

that means in your map function, you can access the  `id, brand, model` properties, but because you can only loop once, you can't loop over the models themselves.

What you need to do, is have a seperate state, for the selected models. and map over that instead. the selected models value would change whenever a car gets reselected

```
  handleChangeCar = event => {
    // Returns an array with objects that pass the filter condition, 
    // meaning it will return an array with only one object
    const returnSelectedBrand = this.state.cars.filter(function(result) {
      return result.brand === event.target.value;
    });
    this.setState({ 
      selectedBrand: event.target.value,
      selectedBrandModels: returnSelectedBrand[0].models
    });
  };
```

and map over that instead.

```
    <select>
    {
      // if selectedBrandModel is truthy, map it
      selectedBrandModels && selectedBrandModels.map((model, i) => {
        return (
          // you might need to add an id for each model, we're using
          // the loop index for now
        <option key={i}>
          {model}
        </option>
        )
      })
    }
  </select>
```

Here's the full working code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class simpleData extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cars: [],
      // Renamed to 'selectedBrand' instead of model
      selectedBrand: "",
      // added 'selectedBrandModels to keep track of the selected brand's models
      selectedBrandModels: []
    };

    this.handleSubmitCar = this.handleSubmitCar.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmitCar(event) {
    alert("Your selected value is: " + this.state.models);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  handleChangeCar = event => {
    // Returns an array with objects that pass the filter condition, meaning it
    // will return an array with only one object
    const returnSelectedBrand = this.state.cars.filter(function(result) {
      return result.brand === event.target.value;
    });
    this.setState({ 
      selectedBrand: event.target.value,
      selectedBrandModels: returnSelectedBrand[0].models
    });
  };

  getUnique(arr, comp) {
    const unique = arr
      //store the comparison values in array
      .map(e => e[comp])

      // store the keys of the unique objects
      .map((e, i, final) => final.indexOf(e) === i && i)

      // eliminate the dead keys & store unique objects
      .filter(e => arr[e])

      .map(e => arr[e]);

    return unique;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const cars = require("./cars.json");
    this.setState({ cars: cars });
  }

  render() {
    const uniqueCar = this.getUnique(this.state.cars, "brand");
    // used object deconstructoring for clearer syntax
    const { selectedBrandModels } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>      
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmitCar}>
          <br />
          <br />
          <label>
            Car brand
            <select
              value={this.state.models}
              onChange={this.handleChangeCar}
            >
              {uniqueCar.map(models => (
                <option key={models.id} value={models.brand}>
                  {models.brand}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" /><br/>
          Car Model
            <select>
            {
              // if selectedBrandModel is truthy, map it
              selectedBrandModels && selectedBrandModels.map((model, i) => {
                return (
                  // you might need to add an id for each model, we're using
                  // the loop index for now
                <option key={i}>
                  {model}
                </option>
                )
              })
            }
          </select>

        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT: I realised you could also just map the selected car object directly instead of making a separate state for its models, something like:

```
              selectedCar && 
              selectedCar.models.map((model, i) => {
              // or selectedCar[0].models.map if its an array
                return (
                  // you might need to add an id for each model, we're using
                  // the loop index for now
                <option key={i}>
                  {model}
                </option>
                )
              })
            }
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked as I wanted it to be.